# Can I use a variable of type varchar with possible dots in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, authentication, triggers

I'm creating a procedure to add users logins to a specific database. I call this procedure inside a trigger when a user is inserted in my database (I want to have different logins for each user in my site and in the access to the database).

Here's my trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[sys_users_insert]
ON [dbo].[sys_users]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @USERNAME varchar(MAX)

    SELECT @USERNAME = INSERTED.username    
    FROM INSERTED

    EXEC CreateUser @USERNAME
END
```

The `CreateUser` is my procedure to create the logins in the database. The procedure is working. When I call it from a query editor:

```
EXEC CreateUser 'patricia.santos'
```

The user is created with success. But when I insert a user in the table and trigger runs the user isn't created nor is inserted in the table. And I found out that if I insert a user without dots in the username everything goes ok. So I believe is something with the dot but I would like to know if there's some workaround to accept usernames with dots.

UPDATE

Here's my procedure for creating logins in my database:

```
USE mydatabase
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser]
    @USERNAME AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN

declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)

If NOT EXISTS(select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where name = @USERNAME)
BEGIN

    set @sql = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @USERNAME + 
            ' WITH 
                PASSWORD = ''something'',
                CHECK_POLICY = OFF'

    exec(@sql)

    set @sql = 'ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER ' + @username

    exec(@sql)

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @USERNAME)
    BEGIN

        -- Creates a database user for the login created above.
        set @sql = 'CREATE USER [' + @USERNAME + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @USERNAME + ']'

        exec(@sql)

        EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', @USERNAME
    END
END

END
```

Thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure how your example is working at all in any scenario. You have a comma after you declare @USERNAME variable with no other variable declarations following. Is this simply a copy paste error in your example?

Comment: @EdmondQuinton I'm sorry it was a copy paste error. Already edited my question. :)

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @USERNAME = INSERTED.username FROM INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Also can you provide the sql script for the procedure or at the very least the procedure's signature?

Comment: @marc_s in my project only one user is inserted at the time, you can't create more than one user at once. But I can rewrite it to just in case deal with that. Moreover, this isn't my problem (at least for now) because it runs ok with usernames that doesn't have dots.

Comment: @EdmondQuinton already edited my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue may be with your CreateUser procedure. Ensure that the “CREATE USER” clause and ALTER SERVER ROLE clause wraps the user name in square brackets. Please see updated procedure below:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser]
        @USERNAME AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    AS
    BEGIN

    declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)

    If NOT EXISTS(select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where name = @USERNAME)
    BEGIN

        set @sql = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @USERNAME + '] ' +
                ' WITH 
                    PASSWORD = ''something'',
                    CHECK_POLICY = OFF'

        exec(@sql)

        set @sql = 'ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [' + @username + ']'

        exec(@sql)

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @USERNAME)
        BEGIN

            -- Creates a database user for the login created above.
            set @sql = 'CREATE USER [' + @USERNAME + '] FOR LOGIN [' + @USERNAME + ']'

            exec(@sql)

            EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', @USERNAME
        END
    END

    END
```

Let me know if this helps at all.